Token with a sell tax
My issue is that i want to launch a token that incorporates a custom sell tax as a bot protection. The docs i have read seem to point towards using the Token2022 standard with a custom transfer hook. However, Raydium does not support this feature currently, so i cannot use this workaround. My questions are:

Is there a token contract out there i can fork to achieve this custom sell tax?
Are there any other workarounds possible? (eg other DEX, bit i was not able to find one yet that supports token2022 transfer hooks)

greetings

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you read about transfer fees for your token? https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees
